# ¿Como convertir un JSON a un Objeto con javaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Espero me puedan apoyar con esta duda, tengo un JSON de la siguiente manera:

```
const Dias = [{"dia": "05/02/2024"},{"dia": "21/03/2024"},{"dia": "01/05/2024"}]
```

Lo que me gustaría es obtenerlos de la siguiente forma:

```
const Dias= ['05/02/2024', '21/03/2024', '01/05/2024']
```

¿Hay alguna manera de solo obtener la fecha y colocarlo de esa manera?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Tienes suficiente reputación como para saber que a tu pregunta le falta algún [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aclaración: Un Json es un `string` el cual tiene un formato estandarizado. Lo que tu tienes en el primer código es la declaración de un array con objetos en su interior (*que se ven similares, pero son cosas distintas*).

Para obtener un array de solo días usas la función `map`, la cual entrega un nuevo array con la misma cantidad de valores, pero con la posibilidad de convertirlos en otra cosa. En tu caso convertirlos desde un objeto a solo a un string

```js
const Dias = [{"dia": "05/02/2024"},{"dia": "21/03/2024"},{"dia": "01/05/2024"}];

const solo_dias = Dias.map(a=>a.dia);

console.log(solo_dias);
```